# Sum consecutive integers using while statement

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

```
def sum_from_to(start, end):
    """Return the sum of the integers from start up to but not including end.

    sum_from_to(int, int) -> int
    """

    while
```

### Examples:

- sum_from_to(3, 7) should evaluate to 18 (i.e. 3+4+5+6).
- sum_from_to(3, 3) should evaluate to 0.

how would I approach this?

Comment: Why do you need to use a `while` loop? You can just do `sum(range(low, hi))` (use `xrange` instead of `range` in 2.x).

Comment: range(start, end, step) might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for fun, you could solve this purely mathematically using the euler summation formula:

```
def sum_from_to(start,stop):
    return ((stop-1)*stop-(start-1)*start)/2

sum_from_to(3,7) #18
```

This has the benefit of being very computationally inexpensive. No loops, no ranges, arrays, what have you. The other functions are expensive by comparison.

Comment: This is a `SyntaxError` as written. (There's a reason the prof called the parameters `start` and `stop` instead of `from` and `to`…) Also, `//` isn't a comment in Python, it's division.

Comment: Bit rusty on my python, thanks for the correction.

Comment: No problem. You also had only 1 space instead of 4 for one of your code lines, but I fixed that rather than just add another comment.

Answer (score 1):

there is simpler solution.

```
sum(range(3, 7))
```

this will not include the end value. so you will get exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

First, if this isn't a homework problem, the answer is trivial:

```
def sum_from_to(start, end):
    return sum(range(start, end))
```

In Python 2.x, use `xrange` instead of `range`. That's it.

If this is a homework program, and you're not allowed to use `sum` or `range` or even a `for` loop (at which point I have to wonder why they're even pretending to teach you Python, but whatever…), here's a skeleton:

```
def sum_from_to(start, end):
    total = 0
    value = start
    while ???:
        total = ???
        value = ???
    return total
```

You need to fill in the "???" parts. How do you make `value` keep counting up, 1 at a time, until it reaches `end`? What do you do to `total` to make it keep a running sum? That's really all there is to it.

As a further hint:

You can use the old value of a variable to make the new value. For example:

```
i = 1
i = i * 2 # now it's 2
i = i * 2 # now it's 4
```

Comment: thanks you so much abarnert! yes it is a homework problem does this mean i would have value = start+1? still not sure what to do with total though?

Comment: No, if you do `value = start + 1` each time through the loop, and you call it with, say, `sum_from_to(3, 7)`, you'll set `value = 3 + 1` each time. You want value to be 3, then 4, then 5, then 6, etc., right? See the further hint to see if it helps (with both of your questions). And feel free to ask further questions if you're still stuck.

Comment: ummm would i go value = int + 1??

Comment: What's `int`? It's a function that turns things into integers. Why would you add `1` to a function? Did you look at the hint, where I show `i = i * 2` to double `i`?

Comment: ohhh sooo value = value +1 ??

Comment: Closer… but just doing `value + 1` just adds `value` and `1` and throws the result away, because you haven't done anything with it (assigned it to a variable, passed it to a function, etc.).